# PHP rename variable to unique value returns 1

Tags: php, csv, rename

I have a file name which I need to give a unique name to in PHP. The file looks like this:

> orders_dd-mm-yy#hh:mm:ss.csv

I want to change it to:

> orders_dd-mm-yy_uniquevalue.csv

As I believe the hash and colons are causing issues when I try to import the CSV file into an SQL database.

However when I use this code to change the variable, it becomes a '1':

```
$file = rename('/var/www/html/' . $file, '/var/www/html/' . explode('#', $file))[0] . '_' . uniqid() . '.csv';
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @bipinpatel I do have it like that in my actual code, I'll fix that on the question, sorry.

Comment: I found something that might not be the best answer but works... Keep the old path in a variable (let say $f), the new path in another one ($new) and just run `\`mv $f $new\`;`

Comment: [`rename`](https://php.net/manual/function.rename.php) returns a `bool` showing whether the file could be renamed or not. You're assigning that success value to `$file`.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Yoshi's comment, I have been able to figure out where I was going wrong.

This has worked for me:

```
$fileNew = explode('/var/www/html/' . $file)[0] . '.csv';
rename('/var/www/html/' . $file, '/var/www/html/' . $fileNew);
$file = $fileNew;
```